# The Toggler does not expand

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The toggler somehow doesn't respond when I press on it, basically after pressing nothing happens. I want it to expand on click when the browser window become smaller. Could you suggest a solution. Here is the code:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/top_logo.png" alt="One Million Lines" title="One Million Lines"></a>
    
    <!-- The toggle button is here -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <!-- Info to be displayed is here-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#who">WHO WE ARE<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#get-involved">GET INVOLVED</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is flawless. Make sure you are linking the jquery library before the bootstrap, for example:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
```